# VBA: CountIfS function to count how many times a cell value is Yes across multiple worksheets IF another cell value

Tags: vba, excel, countif

I'm very new to VBA (this week) and I'm using a code

```
Function myCountIf(rng As Range, criteria) As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Summary-Sheet" And ws.Name <> "Notes" And ws.Name <> "Results" Then
        myCountIf = myCountIf + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Range(rng.Address), criteria)
    End If
Next ws
```

End Function

But I want to use the CountIfS function to count how many times a cell value is Yes across multiple worksheets IF another cell value (also across multiple  is also Yes

I've tried:

```
=myCountIf(AND(I8="Yes",I7="Yes"))
```

but it doesn't work

but:

```
=myCountIf(I8,"Yes")
```

works fine

its probably very simple and if so I'm sorry

Comment: If u want to use your function with AND... you need to modify your UDF to match it

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the modified **UDF** below:

```
Option Explicit

Function myCountIfs(Rng1 As Range, Criteria1 As String, Rng2 As Range, Criteria2 As String) As Long

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    Select Case ws.Name
        Case "Summary-Sheet", "Notes", "Results"
            ' do nothing

        Case Else
             myCountIfs = myCountIfs + Application.CountIfs(ws.Range(Rng1.Address), Criteria1, ws.Range(Rng2.Address), Criteria2)

    End Select
Next ws

End Function
```

However, in order to call it from Excel sheet's cells, don't use the regular `=myCountIf(AND(I8="Yes",I7="Yes"))` but the line below :

```
=myCountIfs(I8,"Yes",I7,"Yes")
```

See screen-shot below for example of using this **UDF** in Excel, all sheets have "YES" in cells I7 and I8, but one of the sheet's name is "Note", therefore the result is 2 (and not 3).

[image]

Comment: Thats Great! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This is a small change to give you two filter criteria:

```
Function myCountIfs(rng1 As Range, criteria1, rng2 As Range, criteria2) As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Summary-Sheet" And ws.Name <> "Notes" And ws.Name <> "Results" Then
        myCountIfs = myCountIfs + WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(ws.Range(rng1.Address), criteria1, ws.Range(rng2.Address), criteria2)
    End If
Next ws
```